# Calling external module from Chapel

Tags: makefile, chapel

I am trying to use my [NumSuch](https://github.com/buddha314/numsuch) module in another program.  My `Makefile` includes

```
NUMSUCH_HOME=/home/buddha314/numsuch/src
MODULES=-M$(NUMSUCH_HOME)

yummly: yummlyAnalysis.chpl
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $(MODULES) -o yummlyAnalysis $<
    #$(CC) $(MODULES) -o yummlyAnalysis $<
```

Within the code, I don't want to `use NumSuch` because I don't want to pollute the name space.  I thought I could

```
var g = NumSuch.buildFromSparseMatrix(A, weighted=false, directed=false);
```

But during compilation, I get

```
yummlyAnalysis.chpl:72: error: 'NumSuch' undeclared (first use this function)
Makefile:12: recipe for target 'yummly' failed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with this program is that Chapel doesn't know that `NumSuch` is the name of a module as opposed to a record, class, or typo.  As a result, it doesn't go looking for it in your module search path.  The fix is to let Chapel know that there is a module named `NumSuch`:

One way to do this is via a `use` statement (this asserts that there is a module with the given name, and will cause the compiler to go looking for it if it hasn't already found it).  You can avoid namespace pollution as you'd hoped by using filters that cause no symbols to be made visible within the scope of the `use` statement:

```
use NumSuch only ;     // only make this (empty) list of symbols available
```

or:

```
use NumSuch except *;  // make all symbols available except for `*` (all of them)
```

After either of these statements, your call should work:

```
NumSuch.buildFromSparseMatrix(...);
```

and an unqualified call should not since no symbols were made available via the `use`:

```
buildFromSparseMatrix(...);
```

You could even put the `use` statement into some other scope which would cause the compiler to go looking for the module, find it, know that there's a module with that name, and limit the namespace pollution to that scope (though I consider this stylistically worse compared to the previous, more idiomatic, approaches):

```
{
  use NumSuch;  // causes the compiler to go looking for module NumSuch; limits namespace pollution to this scope...
}
NumSuch.buildFromSparseMatrix(...);
```

A second way to do this is to list the `NumSuch.chpl` source file explicitly on the `chpl` command-line.  By default, all source files named on the command line are parsed and their modules made known to the compiler.